# How do I make the y-axis ticks more prominent using ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have the following code:

Here is the link to [electrons.xlsx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2w50w68i11eo9yr/electrons.xlsx?dl=0)

```
electrons = = Import["electrons.xlsx"];
electronslist = 
  Transpose@{electrons[[1]][[1 ;; All, 2]]/10^20, 
    electrons[[1]][[1 ;; All, 1]]*10^7};
electronsplot = 
 ListLinePlot[electronslist, Frame -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 2}, {-3, 30}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"", ""}, Axes -> None, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20},
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Thick, Orange} , ImageSize -> 400, 
  FrameStyle -> Black, ScalingFunctions -> {Automatic, "Reverse"}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, All}}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> {Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0], 
    Automatic, Automatic, Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0]}]
```

It yields an output like this:
[image]

The y-axis ticks are hardly visible. How can I make them more prominent? I want the ticks to be like the one in the figure below.plot Also is there a way to shade the curve like done here:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tF = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, TicksLength -> {.035, .02}][##] /. 
    AbsoluteThickness[_] -> AbsoluteThickness[2] &;

llp = ListLinePlot[electronslist,
  Frame -> True,
  AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio,
  PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 2}, {-2, 30}}, FrameLabel -> {"", ""},
  Axes -> None,
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20},
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Thick, Orange},
  ImageSize -> 400,
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[2]],
  ScalingFunctions -> {Automatic, "Reverse"},
  FrameTicks -> ConstantArray[tF, {2, 2}],
  FrameTicksStyle -> {FontOpacity -> # & /@ {1, 0}, 
    FontOpacity -> # & /@ {0, 1}}] /. l_Line :> {l, Opacity[.5], FilledCurve[l]}
```

[image]

Post-process to change the automatic formating of tick labels:

```
reFormatLabel = ReplaceAll[t: {_Real, label_, {_Real, _Real}, {___}} :> Rationalize @ t]

reFormatLabel @ llp
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that was useful, can you also please tell me how to shade the area under the  curve just like shown in the example?

Comment: @Indeterminate, please see the update.

Comment: Why is there a decimal point after the numbers on y axis?

Comment: @Indeterminate, that's what is produced by `Charting`ScaledTicks`. Update with a method to re-format the labels.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to do it in while defining tF or ticks itself?

Comment: @Indeterminate, I did try to add the label re-formatting to `tF`, but, somehow it is ignored/overridden by some internal function.

Comment: You can try using `FrameTicks -> {ConstantArray[reFormatLabel@tF[-2, 30], 2], 
  ConstantArray[tF, 2]}` .

Comment: One last thing, how do I remove the minor ticks and keep just the major ticks?

Comment: replace `.02` with `0` in the definition of `tF`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has been a nice mini-tutorial for Ticks in Mathematica!